# Make square brackets also red in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs

In the given below code, it will search for the word with square brackets and replace the color of only that particular. I want to change the color of square brackets along with word.

```
 if (event.match(/([^[]+(?=]))/g)) {
      // event.match(/([^[]+(?=]))/g).style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
      // if (event.includes("[first name]") || event.includes("[insert ticket concern]")||event.includes("[insert information]")) {
      var newTxt = event.split('[');
      let sampleText = event;
      for (var i = 1; i < newTxt.length; i++) {
        let value = newTxt[i].split(']')[0];
        console.log(value, "matchhh");

        sampleText = this.replacecanned(sampleText, value, `<span style="color: red;">${value}</span>`);

      }
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey why don't you try:
```sampleText = this.replacecanned(sampleText, `[${value}]`, `<span style="color: red;">[${value}]</span>`);
```

Comment: Have a nice day :)